# Multiple c language dialects

Tags: ios, c, xcode, c99, c11

I'm trying to integrate a series of code files (Cocos3d files) which by default are gnu-c99, into my project that is to be c11 on account of other libraries its using.

I started manually editing the cocos3d files (mostly it was just struct references that were throwing compiler errors) to compile; but soon realized this was crazy as there a few hundred files.  Of additional note; cocos3d is ARC, and my project isn't; Thus I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to specify some files in your project be built with one language dialect, and others with another (e.g. with compiler flags, or something); if so how?
2. When setting compiler flags for arc (e.g. -fobjc-arc to enable ARC for one file); is there a way to recursively do this for a folder / group of files?

Comment: I feel like you're going about this the wrong way. It's likely that the Cocos3d project has been set up as an independent project that you can include as a dependency into your workspace. I haven't done any research to verify this, but it's pretty common for open-source offerings to be done this way.

Comment: good point.. Hadn't thought of that; will definitely look into it.

Comment: If you want to suggest your comment as an answer I can up vote it for you.  I've also realized that cocos3d produces .a library products of its physics engine, its core code, and cocos2d files; so in the end I think just adding those as library files is probably simplest.  In general, I think your answer is more correct tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ian's comment pointed me in the right direction; In the specific case of Cocos3d, my comment above isn't quite right.  Simply taking the static libraries (.a files) produced as a product of the CC3HelloWorld project and adding them to your own project still doesn't solve multiple language dialect dependancies.

I analyzed the structure of the CC3HelloWorld project closer & noticed that it actually had 4 targets; the main app, cocos3d, cocos2d, and cocos2d-chipmunk.  So I created 3 targets in my new project (file->new->target) and chose the static library option for each.  Then you can drag the source files for cocos3d, 2d, and chipmunk into your project & make sure only to add them to their respective targets (e.g. not to your main app target).

Finally, once you have all the targets setup; you're free to adjust the c and c++ language dialects independently of the other targets under the build settings tab for each target; ditto for ARC.